# Find a Microsoft Word 2010 writing performance plugin

Tags: microsoft-word, writing

I'm looking for Microsoft Word 2010 plugin that would show graphs of document size and my writing speed/performance. A web search provides me with irrelevant results so far.

Measure how many words or pages I write / time I spend writing = performance.

And plot the number of words or pages daily.

I could plot this by hand in excel but it would be time consuming and inefficient and it would not track the amount of time I spend in MS Word, so it would only be limited to the daily page count.